# Windows 8 does not recognize HUAWEI Y536A1 for debugging

Tags: adb, windows, usb-debugging

**The problem:** My device (HUAWEI Y536A1) isn't getting detected in Android Studio

**The solution:** Install the correct usb drivers

**The problem that arises to the solution:** I am not able to...and here are the details:

I have recently system wiped my computer due to slowness. This brings me back to the tedious task of setting up my computer for Android Studio. I have tried **everything** to get  the USB drivers to work in Android Studio, but for some reason, I can't update my USB driver:
[image]

Now, here is the annoying screen that always pops up when trying to update my usb driver:

[image]

My usb driver **is installed:**

[image]

This is pretty pathetic. I have tried everything. **I even tried to go into my computers BIOS and disable Intel xHCI. I also checked, and the virtualization (VT-x) is enabled** I remember when I first started Android, I had this same problem, and the solution was to do something in the computer's BIOS, but the problem still persists.

By the way, I have done lots of research on this topic, and this is a code 28, which means it doesn't have the correct drivers:

[image]

I have been on this for 3 hours now (3 HOURS!) and would really appreciate **any** help. How can I get my phone recognized on my Windows 8 laptop? I have done it before, so I know my phone is compatible. I remember doing something with the bios before I had system wiped my computer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that you have virtualization on in the BIOS.

Next, make sure you have done what I have done in my question.

What I forgot to do was install the `android_winusb` file in the usb_driver folder. The path should be `sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`. In my case, `C:\Users\Ruchir\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`

After doing that, go **back** to device manager and go to the install as path. At the bottom of that should be another option:

> Let me pick from a list of devices on my computer

Select your Android phone; it shouldn't have a yellow exclamation point over it any more. After that, select `Composite ADB Interface`. THAT'S IT.

Comment: After 48 hours from when you posted your question you can accept your own answer by clicking the check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: @karel I know, and I'll accept it day after tomorrow. Any way, I hope this answer will be helpful for others, and save them 7 hours also